# How to get a lot of money in Undertale?

Tags: undertale

I've gotten to the Muffet boss fight, and it's getting annoying. I know you need to eat her donut/cider to let her spare you instantly, but I ate the cheap one in Undyne's fight. Earlier I didn't know about the dog residue, so I sold it. Does anyone know a way to get enough money to buy her crazy expensive donuts?

Comment: It's very possible to beat that fight without grinding for cash (it's certainly not the hardest fight in the game).  It's your call which you'd rather spend your time doing, but you'll almost certainly spend less total time just getting used to her attack patterns.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann Yeah, I remember that being a fairly easy fight once I got used to the patterns.  It took me a little bit; but it was nothing like my first time fighting Asgore for example.